# upload csv file in the background

Tags: php, csv, cakephp, background

I'm uploading one csv file to the server. The file is reading the data and saving into the database but, the problem with my server is the maximum execution time is 180sec. I'm unable to upload all my data in the csv within 180sec. Server is showing like"**Service is unavailable**" after 180 sec. So i decided to complete the **csv upload in the background**. I tried few plugins but i'm getting errors like plugin not found and few other. I need a solution in the **cakephp.** Thanks in advance

Comment: `upload in the background` is not a thing (unless you mean, e.g. ftp). Uploading and _processing_ in the background is a thing, but a very broad topic.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the upload itself takes 180 seconds. You should rethink your design and collect the data first and then write it to the database, maybe using bulk insert if available in cakephp.

Comment: my csv file is having 7000 rows. i'm saving values in to database using api's response.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the execution time like this.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
```

Put this at the top of the CSV upload script. You can change the second parameter according to your need.

Comment: server maximum execution time is 180sec only. I already tried this way. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 – Data Base Connection

At first we need to connect to database…
File Name: connection.php

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("Database", "username", "password") or die("Could not connect.");

if(!$db) 

    die("no db");

if(!mysql_select_db("Databasename",$db))

    die("No database selected.");
?>
```

Step 2 – upload page

Making connection to data base by calling the connection.php, clean the table of its old data, insert new uploaded data into table…
File Name: upload.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Upload page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #E3F4FC;
    font: normal 14px/30px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2b2b2b;
}
a {
    color:#898989;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    color:#CC0033;
}

h1 {
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #CC0033;
}
h2 {
    font: bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #898989;
}
#container {
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 945px;
}
#form           {padding: 20px 150px;}
#form input     {margin-bottom: 20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="form">

<?php

include "connection.php"; //Connect to Database

$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE tablename"; //empty the table of its current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);

//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into tablename(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form
}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

    print "File name to import:<br />\n";

    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to insert data into new rows in the back ground. my csv has 7000 rows.